# Form Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, html

I have an form for file upload and am trying to call an event at the end of the file upload.

I know about onSubmit, however I'm looking for something like onFormProcessed, something to call when all the files are processed.

Comment: A file would get uploaded to a _server_. Javascript is client side. It is really no clear what you want to do here.

Comment: No such thing in client side - it's pure server side issue..

Comment: I understand the process, if there isn't a thing don't downvote just say there isn't. All I'm asking if there's a event that fires before the action occurs or if onSubmit is the only event for a form?

Comment: I suspect that the downvote is because your question is overly short.  It doesn't give us any information about what you are working with, what you are really trying to achieve, what you've already tried, or what techniques you already understand.  This makes it much harder for us to, for example, come up with suggestions that might give you what you need without being exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any form events that fire after onSubmit.  If the the form directs you to another page (and by default most do), you could hang something off of document.onload of the destination page.  Alternately, if you want it to stay on the same page, you could override the submit handler and replace it with an asynchronous call - and those *do* return an event from the server when they're done.  Asynch calls aren't really trivial if you don't know what you're doing, though - you might want to read up on them.